# Driving directions on google maps with autocomplete boxes

Tags: javascript, api, autocomplete, maps

I have a Google map with autocomplete input fields that shows driving directions. Problem is that I got errors because the directionservice uses the input variable instead of the autocompleted variable. How can I fix this?

Demo: http://touristification.com/reisadvies/routekaart.html

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var placeSearch, autocomplete, autocomplete2;



        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

  function initMap() {

    var input1 = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
     var start = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input1);


     var input2 = document.getElementById('locationTextField2');
     var end = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2);    

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {lat: 52.34, lng: 4.87}
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var onChangeHandler = function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

    };
    document.getElementById('locationTextField').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('locationTextField2').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  }


  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById('locationTextField').value,
      destination: document.getElementById('locationTextField2').value,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });




  }
</script>
```

Comment: well, first of all fix that: "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

Comment: If that doesn't work, try passing the start and end as parameters to the calculateAndDisplayRoute and use the directionService with start.geometry.location on the origin and end.geometry.location on the destination.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed but I still got errors.

Comment: Narayon, where exactly do I insert start.geometry.location?

Comment: Instead of this: origin: document.getElementById('locationTextField').value. Don't forget to pass start as a parameter of the function. Then do the same with end.

Comment: I can see that you didn't get the place before trying to calculate the route. I'll elaborate this on an answer, for better legibility.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'place_changed' event instead of a 'change' event, because the 'change' it's triggered every time the input changes and not when the user choose a place from the autocomplete, and don't forget to get the place itself.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(start, 'place_changed',function(){
  var from = start.getPlace();
  // the rest of the code
});
```

Then, on the `calculateAndDisplayRoute` function:

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, from, to) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: from.geometry.location,
    destination: to.geometry.location,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used autocomple`.getPlace().geometry.location` as well as different event handler `google.maps.event.addListener(start, 'place_changed', onChangeHandler1);` that works better. Code style is not very good, was done on in a hurry

http://codepen.io/bora-89/pen/bwJoNY

```js
(function () {
                var placeSearch, autocomplete, autocomplete2;
        
        
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
        
                function initMap() {
                    var input1 = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
                    var start = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input1);
        
        
                    var input2 = document.getElementById('locationTextField2');
                    var end = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2);
        
                    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
                    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 7,
                        center: {lat: 52.34, lng: 4.87}
                    });
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
                    var startLoc, endLoc;
                    var onChangeHandler1 = function () {
                        startLoc = this.getPlace().geometry.location;
                        if (startLoc && endLoc) {
                            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService,
                                    directionsDisplay,
                                    startLoc,
                                    endLoc
                            );
                        }
                    };
                    var onChangeHandler2 = function () {
                        endLoc = this.getPlace().geometry.location;
                        if (endLoc && startLoc) {
                            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService,
                                    directionsDisplay,
                                    startLoc,
                                    endLoc
                            );
                        }
                    };
                    google.maps.event.addListener(start, 'place_changed', onChangeHandler1);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(end, 'place_changed', onChangeHandler2);
        
                }
        
        
                function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, startLoc, endLoc) {
                    console.log(startLoc);
                    console.log(endLoc);
                    directionsService.route({
                        origin: startLoc,
                        destination: endLoc,
                        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                    }, function (response, status) {
                        if (status === 'OK') {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        } else {
                            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                        }
                    });
        
        
                }
            })();
```